# I/O overloading and reading from text files

Tags: c++

I need to define a read and a print function for a class that has an array of objects as a private variable. I have to read in objects from a text file and print them to the screen. To do this I need to overload the << and >> operators. I understand I need to use loops to read and print the information stored in the array but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. My lecturer has given us a skeleton code which is basically function prototypes and the main function which I need to stick to. I understand how this works with public structs as I have done this exact scenario using that but the private variables of class' are tripping me up.

```
class EmployeeList {
public:
  //Constructors
  EmployeeList();
  EmployeeList(istream&);
  //Accessors
  bool isEmpty() const;
  bool isFull() const;
  int size() const; //Number of employees in list
  Employee item(int i) const; //i'th employee
  //Mutators
  void setItem(int i,const Employee& e);
  //I/O functions, sets the i'th emplyee to e
  void read(istream&);
  void print(ostream&) const;

private:
  enum {MAXSIZE = 100};
  Employee list[MAXSIZE];
  int count; //Number of employees in the current list
};

EmployeeList::EmployeeList() {
  count = 0;
}

EmployeeList::EmployeeList(istream& in) {
  //list[MAXSIZE] = in;
}

bool EmployeeList::isEmpty() const {
  return (count == 0);
}

bool EmployeeList::isFull() const {
  return (count == MAXSIZE);
}

int EmployeeList::size() const {
  return count;
}

Employee EmployeeList::item(int i) const {
}

void EmployeeList::setItem(int i, const Employee& e) {
}

void EmployeeList::read(istream& in) {
  Employee tempList;
  while (in >> tempList) {
  }
}

void EmployeeList::print(ostream& out) const {
  for (int i=0; i < size(); i++) {
  }

  cout << out;
}
```

The above part is the Class EmployeeList while the below part are overloading functions. The commented out parts are ideas that I thought might work but didn't.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, EmployeeList& l) {
  l.read(in);
  return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const EmployeeList& l) {
  l.print(out);
  return out;
}
```

Below is the main function given to us.

```
int main() {
  authorInfo();
  ifstream infile("a1in.txt");
  if(!infile) {
      cout << "file 'alin.txt' not found.";
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  EmployeeList theList(infile);

  cout << endl;
  cout << theList.size() << " employees read:\n" << theList << endl;
  process(theList);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Hope someone can steer me in the right direction! Let me know if you need more of the code. Thanks!

EDIT: 
Employee read and print functions:

```
void Employee::read(istream& in) {
  in >> name >> id >> salary;
}

void Employee::print(ostream& out) const {
  out << getName() <<" "<< getID() <<" "<< getSalary() << endl;
}
```

Employee overloading:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Employee& e) {
  e.read(in);
  return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Employee& e) {
  e.print(out);
  return out;
}
```

EDIT 2: Updated read() function. The line with the while is where the error is.

```
void EmployeeList::read(istream& in) {
  Employee inEmployee;
  while (in >> inEmployee && count < MAXSIZE) {
      list[count] = inEmployee;
      count++;
  }
}
```

EDIT 3: Here is the print() function I have so far. It does indeed print but I get the default constructor information rather than information from the file. Is this a read or print function issue? I'm thinking read function still.

```
void EmployeeList::print(ostream& out) const {
  cout << endl;
  for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
      out << list[count];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is the private variable tripping you up? In the public section a quick glance looks like all you should need is there..

Comment: Whitespace in name, id, or salary will break Employee::read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Array Bounds

In your class, you have:

```
Employee list[MAXSIZE];
```

Given this, there is an error the code you tried:

```
EmployeeList::EmployeeList(istream& in) {
  list[MAXSIZE] = in;
}
```

`list` only has elements from `list[0]` to `list[MAXSIZE - 1]`. `list[MAXSIZE]` is one past the end of the array, and is invalid.

## Constructors

That said, I'd strongly recommend against having a constructor that takes an `istream&`. It is far better to construct an empty object with the default constructor, then use its `read(istream&)` method (via `operator <<`) to load the data. In other words, rather than:

```
EmployeeList theList(infile);
```

use:

```
EmployeeList theList;
infile >> theList;
```

If you're *required* to have a constructor that takes an `istream&`, just have it call `read()` after initializing the object:

```
EmployeeList::EmployeeList(istream& in): count(0) {
  read(in);
}
```

Note that *only one constructor is called*, so the initialization in `EmployeeList::EmployeeList()` does not happen in `EmployeeList::EmployeeList(istream&)`. I hear the new version of C++ deals with this unnecessary repetition, but for the time being that's where we are.

## Naming

Another thing: your code will be less confusing with better variable names. In this case:

```
void EmployeeList::read(istream& in) {
  Employee tempList;
  while (in >> tempList) {
  }
}
```

Don't say `tempList` because it's *not* a "temporary list", it's a single `Employee` that has been read. Better would be:

```
void EmployeeList::read(istream& in) {
  Employee inEmployee;
  while (in >> inEmployee) {
    list[count++] = inEmployee;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for sound advice. I disagree with the recommendation against writing a constructor that takes an `istream&`, though: if you want an immutable object loaded from a stream, that's a good way to go about getting it.

Comment: I can see your point, but recommend against it for two reasons: 1) it violates DRY since it has to repeat at least the default constructor's code (fixed in C++11) and 2) implicit typecast from `istream` to `EmployeeList` could be surprising (solved by using the `explicit` keyword). So not a show stopper, but not things I'd want to put in an introductory course ("The C++ you're using is not standard C++, run in fear").

Comment: Do you guys have any thoughts on my current read and print functions? (Edit 2 and 3). I think it's to do with my read function still.

Comment: Put a cerr << inEmployee; in your read() function's while loop. Also, the count < MAXSIZE test should be its own if() statement in the loop, resulting in a print to cerr and a break if the list runs out of space.

Answer (score 0):

You could start off by figuring out how to read in input. The approach, which is likely incomplete, that I would take is this:

```
EmployeeList::EmployeeList(istream& in) {
  count = 0;
  read(in);    // delegate it to avoid duplication
}

void EmployeeList::read(istream& in) {
  Employee tempList;
  while (in >> tempList && count < MAXSIZE) {
    list[count] = tempList;
    ++count;
  }
}
```

You will need to overload `operator>>` for `Employee` class for this to work.

Comment: I am getting an "error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'in >> inEmployee'" when I compile now. Would this be to do with my Employee class? Would it help if you could see that also?

Comment: Have you overloaded `operator>>` for `Employee` class as I suggested? In your code, only overload for `EmployeeList` class is shown.

Comment: Yes I have in the same fashion as with EmployeeList.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that my operator prototype was in the wrong place for the Employee class. All compiles now. Will probably be back with other issues down the line though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework so i'll try to just give you a hint:

```
void EmployeeList::read(istream& in) {

  Employee tempList;
  while (in >> tempList) {
  //here you are creating a tempList so after you fill in the values in tempList 
  //the tempList is to become a part of Employee list[MAXSIZE]; 
  }
}
```

and how do you fill in the values? You do this using your constructor and maintaining the `count`

```
EmployeeList::EmployeeList(istream& in) {
  //here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write this, without the skeleton constraint. Feel free to adapt to your assignment requirements.

Source: http://www.ideone.com/R9EeF

Iostreams are hard to master. You have to read about `std::getline`, the `std::ios` flags and stringstreams to understand how to parse an employee list with them.

I prefer giving you a working template (that you cannot use for your assignment since I don't make use of the skeleton at all), since there is a lot to say about iostreams.

Also feel free to ask questions, so that I can enhance my answer with your actual problems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we can't use stringstream and I'm not sure I would need to? Also we can't use vectors it must use classes. Due to this I don't really know about either of those things which means I can't really follow your code very well.

Comment: @RedFred: I use vector because otherwise it is very difficult to roll back if the read failed. Also stringstream is very convenient once you have read a string delimited by a character, but not strictly necessary. I repeat: writing a correct istream reader is *very* cumbersome, the code I show you is only intended to show a way to do it correctly. It is intended to be read, (at least superficially) understood, and used as a template, not copied and pasted into your assignment.